# Converting numbers with parenthesis to numbers (matlab)

Tags: matlab

I have a text file (contents below) that I am pulling data from into a table in Matlab. Some numbers get stored into the table as " '19' " or similar (with single quotation marks around them); I believe they are stored as a string. As an example, I would like to convert " '19' " from a string to a number, but I am unsure how to do that with the single quotation marks around the number.

Text file (named "SimplifiedLog.txt")(Each line begins with a "<" symbol, but I am unsure of how to get around using that as formatting for posting this):

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>

<log>

  LogEntry Time="8/18/2020 8:25:54 AM" Zone="&lt;0&gt;" Vset="19" Vrdb="0.0" />

  LogEntry Time="8/18/2020 8:25:54 AM" Zone="&lt;1&gt;" Vset="19" Vrdb="0.0" />

</log>
```

My code:

```
data = readtable('SimplifiedLog.txt','FileType','text');

update = tail(data,3);

update.Var5 = regexp(update.Var5, '\d+', 'match', 'once');

update.Var6 = regexp(update.Var6, '\d+', 'match', 'once'); % Truncates the cell down to '19'

update.Var7 = regexp(update.Var7, '\d+', 'match', 'once');

update.Properties.VariableNames = {'Log_Entry' 'Date' 'Time_Stamp' 'AM_PM' 'PSU_Address' 'Set_Voltage' 'Read_Voltage' 'unused'};

important = update(1:2,{'Time_Stamp', 'PSU_Address', 'Set_Voltage', 'Read_Voltage'})'''
```

Comment: Please edit your question properly

Comment: In what way is that?

Comment: In that you have an XML file which you didn't format properly. What exactly is the desired output?